# NestJS TypeORM change type of primary key, will it impact the existing values in the db, how to migrate them safely?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm working with NestJS, There is a BaseEntity which as configuration

```
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
```

But, I would like to change this

```
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;
```

I'm preparing the migration script, but I would like to know, will this impact the existing values in the table or implicit conversion will be handled by DB?

I'm using TypeORM, Postgresql DB.

Comment: Provided that you are preparing a migration, the exact way this conversion will happen is defined by the logic of your migration script. On the other hand, if you were to use `sync` settings without migrations, the conversion would be handled by the setting you choose.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeORM, changing the primary key's type from numeric to string can affect the database's current values, therefore you must handle the migration cautiously. Primary key types are not implicitly converted by PostgreSQL, thus you will need to handle the data migration explicitly.

However, make a backup of your PostgreSQL database before making any changes. Next Use TypeORM to create a new migration script and change the type of the id column. Create custom logic in the migration script to manage the conversion of current number IDs to string IDs. This may include making a new column, updating values, and dropping the old column.

Hope its helpful :)